# How to determine the service pack of Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, service-pack

I am having a sql server 2012 enterprise edition installed on my win 2012 r2 server.

But i am unable to determine whether its installed with service pack or not.
how to find out which service pack is installed ?
Here is my screen shot, and my screen shot says that , its a ent.edition
with version number:11.2.5058.0 .

[image: WHICH-SERVICE-PACK]

When I serached in msdn, i didnot see this version number in any of the service packs of sql server 2012.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute

```
SELECT @@VERSION;
```

Which will give you the relevant information (note the bold, italicised SP1 from the example results)

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 ***(SP1)*** - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)     Oct 19 2012
>   13:38:57      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Developer Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )

Comment: i didnt get the above results after entering select @@version;

Comment: after checking with select @@version query i got the below results :                      Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) 
 Jun 12 2012 13:05:25 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: 11.0.2218.0 is the version number i got from SSMS, select @@version. which one should i believe ? whether from this query OR from the sql server configuration manager --> sql server services--->right click --> go to advanved tab, which produces the result as 11.2.5058.0.

Comment: its very confusing, which one should i believe is the correct version?

Comment: @SPDevJio: Judging by your screenshot, you probably have several SQL Server instances. The one you were connected to when running `select @@version;` was most likely not the one whose properties are shown in your screenshot.

Comment: 11.0.2218.0 is RTM with a securty hotpatch (see http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). The reason that you do not see a SPx is because there is not one applied. There are no 11.2.x SQL Server builds.

Comment: then , pls advice how to determine, the instances in the server for sql server

Comment: @SPDevJio: Instances have names. You should see the names in the Config Manager as well as in the SSMS (connection dialog box, Object Explorer, query windows/tabs).

Comment: You should open a new question for that, however in the services windows that you have open in your screenshot you can see a list of the SQL instances installed on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this website.

https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.be/

You are at SP2

Comment: A link is not an answer. Even if your source is correct.

Comment: In this case I guess this can be accepted.